# How to use SSH to run a local shell script on a remote machine?

Tags: shell, ssh, system-administration, remote-execution

I have to run a local shell script (windows/Linux) on a remote machine.

I have SSH configured on both machine A and B. My script is on machine A which will run some of my code on a remote machine, machine B.

The local and remote computers can be either Windows or Unix based system.

Is there a way to run do this using plink/ssh?

Comment: The same question is already on serverfault: http://serverfault.com/questions/215756/how-do-i-run-a-local-bash-script-on-remote-machines-via-ssh So there's probably no point in migrating this question.

Comment: The question on Server Fault doesn't have as many answers though. Maybe this question should replace that one.

Comment: I like this answer personally: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87405/how-can-i-execute-local-script-on-remote-machine-and-include-arguments

Comment: Furthermore it should obviously be on topic since ssh is a prime tool for software development.

Comment: Coffee and ssh questions do not share the same degree of off-topicness on SO. Voted for reopen.

Comment: can somebody comment on the ENDSSH tag, please?

Comment: @adam-lear, I think this question should be opened. I modified the question to make it such that it fits stackoverflow. The most popular answer here doesnt actually work if you are trying to run a local script on a remote Widows machine and if it has multiple lines. I did figure out a way, and would love to provide the solution. Even though there does exist another post on serverfault, because of the popularity of this question, most people are going to come here.. so making sure that this question is uptodate will be very helpful for visitors.

Comment: @alpha_989 That's fair. I closed this question unilaterally in my not-quite-two-months as a community moderator. It's not a hill I would want to die on now. :) I'll reopen, although that's not a guarantee that it'll stay open if the community in general disagrees. If it gets closed again, I suggest taking it to [meta] for a discussion.

Answer (score 1364):

If Machine A is a Windows box, you can use Plink (part of [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/)) with the -m parameter, and it will execute the local script on the remote server.

```
plink root@MachineB -m local_script.sh
```

If Machine A is a Unix-based system, you can use:

```
ssh root@MachineB 'bash -s' < local_script.sh
```

You shouldn't have to copy the script to the remote server to run it.

Comment: is there an advantage to using the `-s` option?  [this man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sh) leads me to believe that it will process standard input when it's done processing options, whether `-s` is used or not.

Comment: @asia1281 There's no advantage; I chose this technique since it seemed more explicit. It's probably safe to omit the '-s'.

Comment: For a script that requires `sudo`, run `ssh root@MachineB 'echo "rootpass" | sudo -Sv && bash -s' < local_script.sh`.

Comment: @bradley.ayers remember to start the command with a 'space' to skip the history (P.S. you need to have `HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth or ignorespace` to make it work)

Comment: @bradley.ayers in what situations would you need sudo if you are already logging in as root?

Comment: @Agostino, you can add parameters like this: 

`ssh root@MachineB ARG1="arg1" ARG2="arg2" 'bash -s' < local_script.sh`

Credits fully go to @chubbsondubs' answer below.

Comment: It seems the $PATH environment variable is not applied?

Comment: @ElgsQianChen I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you want the path from the local machine to apply to the remote machine? Or do you want some PATH that's normally present on the remote machine to be honored? Regardless, what you need to do is determine where that PATH is set, why you expect it to be set when executing a remote command, and where your expectation is violated, which would best be addressed in a separate question.

Comment: I want the $PATH on the remote machine to be set. Finally I fond the solution, to add the export statements near the top of ~/.bashrc.

Comment: @SpencerBoucher I don't think that's possible. At least in the Unix case, the stdin on the local machine is already handling the stream of the script. I suggest posting a separate question and detailing what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: The above methods are not working for me if I have to execute the local sh file onto a remote machine which requires pem file for authentication

Comment: Jast joking: what will happen if you will have in local_script.sh  "ssh root@MachineB 'bash -s' < local_script.sh" ;)

Comment: @JasonR.Coombs.. I am trying to run a .bat file (similar to the local_scrip.sh) on a Windows machine with your exact command. However, I am finding that if the .bat file has more than 1 line, the second line doesnt get executed. Have you found this to be true?

Comment: @alpha_989: It's been a very long time since I've tried running on SSH server on Windows. I suspect it's a defect or limitation of your SSH server on Windows that it won't take more than one line of input from the SSH command when run non-interactively. I suggest creating a new question and describe exactly which server and client you're using, what you expect, and what you get instead.

Comment: yeah.. I figured it out, but couldn't post an answer here as this question seems to be closed: https://serverfault.com/a/908587/443721

Comment: Just a quick note: Use the `--login` option for `bash` to behave like a normal login shell (e.g. paths are set like defined in `~/.bash-profile` etc.). Use it like `ssh root@MachineB 'bash -ls' < local_script.sh`

Comment: @YvesVanBroekhoven This is old, but the very point of `-s` is to be able to pass arguments to a script that is sourced through stdin: `ssh root@MachineB 'bash -s arg1 arg2' < local_script.sh`. Omitting `-s` would cause `arg1` to be interpreted as the remote script to execute with `arg2` as its first argument. There is no need to use environment variables.

Comment: This answer should the accepted answer and on top of all the others. It's the only one that corresponds exactly to the problem, and it's short and easy. I had to struggle for about an hour considering all the others, until I saw this one.

Comment: Used the following to provide the password from outside the server and to not show the default prompt: `echo "password" | ssh user@server 'sudo --prompt="" --stdin bash -s' < local.sh`

Comment: Is it possible to extend this ability further by running the example local_script.sh via a bastion as well?

Comment: This works to use a bastion:  ```ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh $host1 -W %h:%p" $host2 "bash -s" <  local.sh```

Comment: when forwarding stdin like this, is it encrypted?  eg if we pass ```"secret=var bash -s" < local.sh``` is this safe?

Comment: That probably deserves its own question.

Comment: @JasonR.Coombs What if local_script.sh relies on a local_exe? If I directly run this command, it says local_exe not found.

Answer (score 743):

This is an old question, and Jason's answer works fine, but I would like to add this:

```
ssh user@host <<'ENDSSH'
#commands to run on remote host
ENDSSH
```

This can also be used with su and commands which require user input. (note the `'` escaped heredoc)

Since this answer keeps getting bits of traffic, I would add even more info to this wonderful use of heredoc:

You can nest commands with this syntax, and that's the only way nesting seems to work (in a sane way)

```
ssh user@host <<'ENDSSH'
#commands to run on remote host
ssh user@host2 <<'END2'
# Another bunch of commands on another host
wall <<'ENDWALL'
Error: Out of cheese
ENDWALL
ftp ftp.example.com <<'ENDFTP'
test
test
ls
ENDFTP
END2
ENDSSH
```

You can actually have a conversation with some services like telnet, ftp, etc. But remember that heredoc just sends the stdin as text, it doesn't wait for response between lines

I just found out that you can indent the insides with **tabs** if you use `<<-END`!

```
ssh user@host <<-'ENDSSH'
    #commands to run on remote host
    ssh user@host2 <<-'END2'
        # Another bunch of commands on another host
        wall <<-'ENDWALL'
            Error: Out of cheese
        ENDWALL
        ftp ftp.example.com <<-'ENDFTP'
            test
            test
            ls
        ENDFTP
    END2
ENDSSH
```

(I think this should work)

Also see
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

Comment: you can temporize a bit by adding lines such as:
# $(sleep 5)

Comment: note that with single quotes around the terminator (`<<'ENDSSH'`), the strings will not be expanded, variables will not be evaluated.  You can also use `<<ENDSSH` or `<<"ENDSSH"` if you want expansion.

Comment: `Expect` can be used when you need to automate interactive commands like FTP.

Comment: Now how could I send a HEREDOC to a remote host over SSH, from a shell script locally?

Comment: Note that I had a `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.` message. One has to use ssh with `-t -t` params to avoid that. See this [thread on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114990/pseudo-terminal-will-not-be-allocated-because-stdin-is-not-a-terminal)

Comment: This option didn't work for me as each line executed as if called with ssh user@server 'line', while I required all lines executed in a single environment. With Jason's answer everything works as required.

Comment: If you're trying to use the <<-'END' syntax, be sure your heredoc ending delimiter is indented using TABs, not spaces. Note that copy/paste from stackexchange will give you spaces. Change those to tabs and the indent feature should work.

Comment: I upvoted this and my vote was counted as down vote.... weird, now I can't change it

Comment: If password requested during ssh login then all commands will be spit out and interpreted as input.

Comment: if i am using <<ENDSSH (without quotes). and inside running a command that uses awk's variables say NR. how do i escape the NR variable. \NR doesn't work

Comment: On MacOS, `ENDSSH`, `ENDFTP` etc, should be write at beginning of line.Otherwise, a warning `-bash: line 3: ENDSSH: command not found` will be output.

Comment: Big thanks to Lorance Chen for your information about difference in MacOS - I had this problem now, so I think that it should be added into @Yarek T

Comment: The only thing I can criticize in this answer is its link to the ABS "documentation" -- the whole reason the [Wooledge BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) was written was to have something less riddled with bad-practice examples than the ABS, forcing us denizens of the freenode #bash IRC channel to help people unlearn bad habits they picked up there.

Comment: Heredocs are great but it is worth mentioning that this method works if you know the accounts shell or make sure you only use POSIX syntax. If you are not sure, adding the "bash -s" before the script is safer.

Comment: @maackle It is incorrect to say that  `<<"ENDSSH"` can be used if you want expansion. Expansions will not occur in a HEREDOC if any part of the _word_ representing the  delimiter is quoted.

Comment: I wrote a script that uses this heredoc method. How can I prevent all the commands in the heredoc from being echoed on the machine sending the commands?

Answer (score 270):

Also, don't forget to escape variables if you want to pick them up from the destination host.

This has caught me out in the past.

For example:

```
user@host> ssh user2@host2 "echo \$HOME"
```

prints out /home/user2

while

```
user@host> ssh user2@host2 "echo $HOME"
```

prints out /home/user

Another example:

```
user@host> ssh user2@host2 "echo hello world | awk '{print \$1}'"
```

prints out "hello" correctly.

Comment: However be aware of the following:  
`ssh user2@host 'bash -s'  
echo $HOME  
/home/user2  
exit`

Comment: Just to add that in `for` loops running in `ssh` session the loop variable must not be escaped.

Comment: In many situations, the sane way to fix your last example would be `ssh user2@host2 'echo hello world' | awk '{ print $1 }'` i.e. run the Awk script locally.  If the remote command produces an immense about of output, you want to avoid copying it all back to the local server, of course.  Incidentally, single quotes around the remote command avoid the need for any escaping.

Answer (score 174):

This is an extension to YarekT's answer to combine inline remote commands with passing ENV variables from the local machine to the remote host so you can parameterize your scripts on the remote side:

```
ssh user@host ARG1=$ARG1 ARG2=$ARG2 'bash -s' <<'ENDSSH'
  # commands to run on remote host
  echo $ARG1 $ARG2
ENDSSH
```

I found this exceptionally helpful by keeping it all in one script so it's very readable and maintainable.

Why this works.  ssh supports the following syntax:

> ssh user@host remote_command

In bash we can specify environment variables to define prior to running a command on a single line like so:

> ENV_VAR_1='value1' ENV_VAR_2='value2' bash -c 'echo $ENV_VAR_1 $ENV_VAR_2'

That makes it easy to define variables prior to running a command.  In this case echo is our command we're running.  Everything before echo defines environment variables.

So we combine those two features and YarekT's answer to get:

> ssh user@host ARG1=$ARG1 ARG2=$ARG2 'bash -s' <<'ENDSSH'...

In this case we are setting ARG1 and ARG2 to local values. Sending everything after user@host as the remote_command.  When the remote machine executes the command ARG1 and ARG2 are set the local values, thanks to local command line evaluation, which defines environment variables on the remote server, then executes the bash -s command using those variables.  Voila.

Comment: Note that if you want to pass args like -a then you can use --. e.g. 'ssh user@host -- -a foo bar 'bash -s' <script.sh'. And the args can also go after the redirect e.g.  'ssh user@host 'bash -s' <script.sh -- -a foo bar'.

Comment: If any of the env var values contain spaces, use: `ssh user@host "ARG1=\"$ARG1\" ARG2=\"$ARG2\"" 'bash -s' <<'ENDSSH'...`

Comment: Like I wrote in another comment, the very point of using `-s` is to be able to apply arguments to scripts that are sourced through stdin. I mean, you may as well omit it if you're not going to use it. If you do use it, there is no reason to use environment variables: `ssh user@host 'bash -s value1 value2' <<< 'echo "$@"'`

Answer (score 113):

```
<hostA_shell_prompt>$ ssh user@hostB "ls -la"
```

That will prompt you for password, unless you have copied your hostA user's public key to the authorized_keys file on the home of user .ssh's directory. That will allow for passwordless authentication (if accepted as an auth method on the ssh server's configuration)

Comment: Voted you up. This is a valid solution. Obviously, the keys must be protected, but they can also be invalidated just like a password via the server side.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The example shows how to run a remote command, but not how to execute a local script on a remote machine.

Comment: Not certain but can't you pipe your script on hostA to run on hostB using this method?

Answer (score 28):

I've started using [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/) for more sophisticated operations. Fabric requires Python and a couple of other dependencies, but only on the client machine. The server need only be a ssh server. I find this tool to be much more powerful than shell scripts handed off to SSH, and well worth the trouble of getting set up (particularly if you enjoy programming in Python). Fabric handles running scripts on multiple hosts (or hosts of certain roles), helps facilitate idempotent operations (such as adding a line to a config script, but not if it's already there), and allows construction of more complex logic (such as the Python language can provide).

Answer (score 25):

```
cat ./script.sh | ssh <user>@<host>
```

Comment: Interestingly, this method of 'cat script.sh | ssh user@host' is the only one that is working for me to run a shell script on another host.

the 'bash' < script.sh method is not working correctly, but I didn't spend time troubleshooting that.

I even copied the script to the remote host, and I see 'file not found', even though if I login to the host and run the script, it works.

Comment: How about cat ./script.sh | ssh -i ~\\.ssh\\id_rsa <user>@<host>  'bash -'

Answer (score 15):

```
chmod +x script.sh    
ssh -i key-file root@111.222.3.444 < ./script.sh
```

Comment: I don't think the `chmod +x` is necessary or useful in this case. The script isn't executed on the local host, it's read on the local host, and only its content is sent to the remote host and executed there. The remote host doesn't even know the content came from a file and thus doesn't care about the permissions of the file.

Answer (score 11):

Try running `ssh user@remote sh ./script.unx`.

Comment: This only works if the script is in the default (home) directory on the remote. I think the question is how to run a script stored locally on the remote.

Comment: ssh username@ip "chmod +x script.sh" <br/> ssh username@ip "path to sh file in remote host"

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you mean you want to do this automatically from a "local" machine, without manually logging into the "remote" machine, you should look into a TCL extension known as Expect, it is designed precisely for this sort of situation.  I've also provided a link to a script for logging-in/interacting via SSH.

https://www.nist.gov/services-resources/software/expect

http://bash.cyberciti.biz/security/expect-ssh-login-script/

Answer (score 7):

```
ssh user@hostname ". ~/.bashrc;/cd path-to-file/;. filename.sh"
```

highly recommended to source the environment file(.bashrc/.bashprofile/.profile). before running something in remote host because target and source hosts environment variables may be deffer.

Comment: This does not explain how to move a local script to the remote host.

Comment: it seems that a space is missing before ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 5):

I use this one to run a shell script on a remote machine (tested on /bin/bash):

```
ssh deploy@host . /home/deploy/path/to/script.sh
```

Answer (score 4):

If the script is short and is meant to be embedded inside your script and you are running under `bash` shell and also `bash` shell is available on the remote side, you may use `declare` to transfer local context to remote. Define variables and functions containing the state that will be transferred to the remote. Define a function that will be executed on the remote side. Then inside a here document read by `bash -s` you can use `declare -p` to transfer the variable values and use `declare -f` to transfer function definitions to the remote.

Because `declare` takes care of the quoting and will be parsed by the remote `bash`, the variables are properly quoted and functions are properly transferred. You may just write the script locally, usually I do one long function with the work I need to do on the remote side. The context has to be hand-picked, but the following method is "good enough" for any short scripts and is safe - should properly handle all corner cases.

```
somevar="spaces or other special characters"
somevar2="!@#$%^"
another_func() {
    mkdir -p "$1"
}
work() {
    another_func "$somevar"
    touch "$somevar"/"$somevar2"
}
ssh user@server 'bash -s' <<EOT
$(declare -p somevar somevar2)    # transfer variables values
$(declare -f work another_func)   # transfer function definitions
work                              # call the function
EOT
```

Answer (score 3):

It's easiest to explain a solution for what the OP is asking for by using a demo:

1. Create a local script however you want. You don't need to set the executable bit. In this example, I use a [here document](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

   ```
   cat <<END >demo.sh
   > echo "Script executed on ${HOSTNAME} with args: $@"
   > END
   ```
2. Using `ssh` run the local script on the remote host.

   Both ways work:

   ```
   cat demo.sh | ssh host bash -s -- hello world
   ```

   or

   ```
   ssh host bash -s -- hello world < demo.sh
   ```

   In either case, you'll see the following output (with `HOSTNAME` replaced with the remote hostname):

   ```
   Script executed on HOSTNAME with args: hello world
   ```

> **Notes**
>
> - Using `-s` tells bash to read from stdin (see [6.1 Invoking Bash](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoking-Bash)).
> - Using `--` ensures the following arguments are passed to the script, not to `bash`.

Comment: That's the cleanest answer, if you intend to use parameters with the script.

Answer (score 2):

This bash script does ssh into a target remote machine, and run some command in the remote machine, do not forget to install expect before running it (on mac `brew install expect` )

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set username "enterusenamehere"
set password "enterpasswordhere"
set hosts "enteripaddressofhosthere"
spawn ssh  $username@$hosts
expect "$username@$hosts's password:"
send -- "$password\n"
expect "$"
send -- "somecommand on target remote machine here\n"
sleep 5
expect "$"
send -- "exit\n"
```

Comment: this is great if you must use passwords ... however for benefit of anyone watching at home any ssh command should use a pair of public+private keys not passwords ... once in place update your ssh server to shut off passwords entirely

Answer (score 2):

if you wanna execute command like this

`` temp=`ls -a`
echo $temp ``

command in `` will cause errors.

below command will solve this problem

`` ssh user@host '''
temp=`ls -a`
echo $temp
''' ``

Answer (score 1):

The answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2732991/4752883) works great if
you're trying to run a script on a remote linux machine using `plink` or `ssh`.
It will work if the script has multiple lines on `linux`.

**However, if you are trying to run a batch script located on a local
`linux/windows` machine and your remote machine is `Windows`, and it consists
of multiple lines using **

`plink root@MachineB -m local_script.bat`

wont work.

Only the first line of the script will be executed. This is probably a
limitation of `plink`.

### Solution 1:

To run a multiline batch script (especially if it's relatively simple,
consisting of a few lines):

If your original batch script is as follows

```
cd C:\Users\ipython_user\Desktop 
python filename.py
```

you can combine the lines together using the "&&" separator as follows in your
`local_script.bat` file:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8055390/4752883:

```
cd C:\Users\ipython_user\Desktop && python filename.py
```

After this change, you can then run the script as pointed out here by
@JasonR.Coombs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2732991/4752883 with:

```
`plink root@MachineB -m local_script.bat`
```

### Solution 2:

If your batch script is relatively complicated, it may be better to use a batch
script which encapsulates the plink command as well as follows as pointed out
here by @Martin https://stackoverflow.com/a/32196999/4752883:

```
rem Open tunnel in the background
start plink.exe -ssh [username]@[hostname] -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 -i "[SSH
key]" -N

rem Wait a second to let Plink establish the tunnel 
timeout /t 1

rem Run the task using the tunnel
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.1\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH qidash.R

rem Kill the tunnel
taskkill /im plink.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [runoverssh](https://github.com/yuriescl/runoverssh):

```sh
sudo apt install runoverssh
```

```sh
runoverssh -s localscript.sh user host1 host2 host3...
```

`-s` runs a local script remotely

---

**Useful flags:**
`-g` use a global password for all hosts (single password prompt)
`-n` use SSH instead of sshpass, useful for public-key authentication

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear if the local script uses locally set variables, functions, or aliases.

If it does this should work:

myscript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

myalias $myvar
myfunction $myvar
```

It uses `$myvar`, `myfunction`, and `myalias`. Let us assume they is set locally and not on the remote machine.

Make a bash function that contains the script:

```
eval "myfun() { `cat myscript.sh`; }"
```

Set variable, function, and alias:

```
myvar=works
alias myalias='echo This alias'
myfunction() { echo This function "$@"; }
```

And "export" `myfun`, `myfunction`, `myvar`, and `myalias` to `server` using `env_parallel` from GNU Parallel:

```
env_parallel -S server -N0  --nonall myfun ::: dummy
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's one script it's fine with the above solution.

I would set up **Ansible** to do the Job. It works in the same way (Ansible uses ssh to execute the scripts on the remote machine for both Unix or Windows).

It will be more structured and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Extending answer from @cglotr. In order to write inline command use `printf`, it useful for simple command and it support multiline using char escaping '\n'

example :

```
printf "cd /to/path/your/remote/machine/log \n tail -n 100 Server.log" | ssh <user>@<host> 'bash -s'
```

See don't forget to add bash -s

Answer (score 0):

I created a solution that works better for me by combining the use of a heredoc from Yarek T's answer with the piped cat method from cglotr's answer along with some other tricks for non-interactive login (using sshpass), using variables from the local and remote host in the script, and enabling sudo commands. The code is longer just because it includes some additional tricks that are likely desired, but the original questioner didn't ask for them.

The problem I have with Yarek's answer is that all the warnings and commands in the heredoc print to the screen. The problem I have with cglotr's answer is that is requires a script file and a complex command with additional interaction to execute the script. With my solution, I write a script that does everything by simply calling the script with the remote host IP address as the first argument like this:

```
./MYSCRIPT REMOTE_IP_ADDRESS
```

The script to be run on the remote host is saved to a variable within the script on the local host using a heredoc so that you don't need to do any quote escaping. Then, the variable containing the script is echo piped to sshpass. Be sure to indent the commands with tabs and not spaces (you'll get spaces instead of tabs when you copy the code). Here is an example of the remote script within the local script.

```
!/bin/bash
# Input argument 1 should be the target host IP address (required)
RX_IP="/(\b25[0-5]|\b2[0-4][0-9]|\b[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}/"
IS_IP=$(echo $1 | sed -nr "${RX_IP}p" | wc -l)
if (( $IS_IP )); then
    USERNAME=remoteuser
    HOSTNAME=$1
    # Export the SSH password to environment variable for sshpass and sudo.
    # The space before the command prevents saving the command to history.
     export SSHPASS=mypassword;
    while read -r -d '' SCRIPT <<-EOS
        # Enable sudo commands with the following command.
        # The space before echo prevents saving the command to history.
         echo $SSHPASS | sudo -Sv
        # Do stuff here. Escape variables to be be accessed on the remote host.
        # For example, escape print variable in an awk command:
        # This command lists all USB block device partitions.
        ls -l /dev /dev/mapper | awk '/^b/ && /sd[a-z][1-9]/ {print \$10}'
        exit
    EOS
    echo "$SCRIPT" | sshpass -e ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null ${USERNAME}@${HOSTNAME} &>/dev/null
    echo 'DONE'
else
    echo "Missing IP address of target host."
    echo "Usage: ./SCRIPT_NAME IP_ADDRESS
fi
```

You need to install sshpass on the local host like this (for Debian based distros).

```
sudo apt install sshpass
```

Answer (score -1):

There is another approach ,you can copy your script in your host with scp command then execute it easily .

Answer (score -20):

First, copy the script over to Machine B using scp

> [user@machineA]$ scp /path/to/script user@machineB:/home/user/path

Then, just run the script

> [user@machineA]$ ssh user@machineB "/home/user/path/script"

This will work if you have given executable permission to the script.

Comment: hi
i applied recommended suggession but it give me following error
[oracle@node1 ~]$ ssh oracle@node2:./home/oracle/au/fs/conn.sh
ssh: node2:./home/oracle/au/fs/conn.sh: Name or service not known
[oracle@node1 ~]$

Comment: 'ssh oracle@node2:./home/oracle/au/fs/conn.sh'? Wrong command line, the command name should be separated from the user@host part with a space, not a colon.

Comment: I'm downvoting this because it's primary claim that it can't be run without copying it over is incorrect.

Comment: It would have been helpful is Jason added why that's incorrect instead of simply stating the fact. Unhelpful.

Comment: [user@machineA]$ ssh root@MachineB 'bash -s' < /machinea/path/to/script

Comment: and yet this is better than most answers