# Run java program on remote UNIX machine in JSP

Tags: java, apache, jsp

I am developing Web Application in local machine using JSP. I want to execute a Java Program that resides on Unix box from my local JSP file. I have all the credentials of the UNIX box. Can you please advise me.

Comment: Tastes like [RMI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html).

Comment: Don't try to do that kind of stuff from your JSP! JSP is meant to be a pure view technology: it's used to output HTML for the browser to consume. Your logic (including interaction with other hosts) should be in a Servlet (or Action, if you use a framework such as Struts).

Answer (score 1):

Well there are various ways to execute [instruct remote machine to execute your java program]

- [RMI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html)
- [WebServices](http://java.sun.com/webservices/tutorial.html)
- Defining your protocol and then [Socket server client](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/)

Comment: Can you please provide me any sample program where I can call remote program from local JSP

Comment: Have you checked the hyperlink ?

Comment: yes. sorry did not find my answer. I am not much into java j2ee. I am just trying to do a POC to execute a java program in UNIX from local JSP. Can you please help me or guide me if I missed something in the hyper link provided by you.

Comment: Or  simply check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001179/unix-ssh-script-running-commands-on-remote-server