# script to SSH to a machine and do SCP

Tags: ssh, scp

I have a scenario -

I'll be logged in machineA. From there I need to ssh to machineB. From machineB I have to copy a file to machineC.

I'm trying to do this in a single step:

```
[user@machineA]$ ssh user@machineB "scp /path/to/file root@machineC:"
```

But this command fails with error:

```
Host key verification failed. lost connection
```

Could someone help?

I need this for a real use.

I do development in machineA, so I will be coding and cross-compiling here. I need to copy my cross compiled binary to machineC for testing. However, direct connection machineA --> machineC won't work. I need to use machineB in between.

Also, machineB and machineA are mirrored; so i don't have to explicitly copy my file from machineA to machieB. I don't use machineB for development just because it is in remote site and will be slow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine

Comment: hrm, this works for me. Try first ssh'ing manually to both servers, are you sure the correct host keys are cached?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `-t` flag so that a tty is allocated. You need this so that you can be prompted for a password to machineC.

```
ssh -t user@machineB "scp /path/to/file root@machineC:/path"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
scp -P PORT USER@IP_SERVER:filename .
```