# Execute Bash script stored in a file over SSH

Tags: bash, ssh

Say I have the following Bash script stored in the file `foo.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo foo
```

Without having to `scp` the file, how could I execute the script stored in `foo.sh` on a remote machine?

I have tried the following (with a few variations) to no success:

```
$ ssh root@remote eval `cat foo.sh`
```

`` eval `cat foo.sh` ``seems to expand to `eval #!/bin/bash echo foo` here

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use ssh to run shell script on a remote machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine)

Comment: You'll of course want to set up SSH so that it doesn't require a password: http://www.csua.berkeley.edu/~ranga/notes/ssh_nopass.html

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
ssh root@MachineB 'bash -s' < local_script.sh
```

I got it from that thread: [How to use SSH to run a shell script on a remote machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine)

Comment: And how can I pass arguments to that script?

Comment: @Agostino: if you need to call local_script.sh with some arguments, just pass the name of a script calling local_script.sh with the necessary arguments, instead of calling local_script.sh directly :)

Comment: I'd like to have it as a one liner. Could you make a small code example?

Comment: Really nice that you provide the source link!

Comment: I need to execute this script in an automated environment. Any idea how I can provide ssh password?

Answer (score 10):

In accepted answer I see:

> I'd like to have it as a one liner. Could you make a small code example?

That should be it:

```
ssh root@MachineB 'bash -s -- uno' < local_script.sh
```

or better, with a here-in document

```
ssh root@MachineB 'bash -s -- uno' <<\EOF
> date
> echo $1
> EOF
jue sep 18 13:01:25 CEST 2014
uno
```

Answer (score 2):

`cat foo.sh | ssh -T root@remote` will to the trick. The `-T` option suppresses a warning you would otherwise get because you're piping input from a file.

Comment: Hear hear on the useless use of cat. ssh root@remote < foo.sh will do the trick.

Comment: How do you pass variables to `foo.sh`?

Answer (score 2):

```
cat foo.sh | ssh HOSTNAME
```

Now tested, though: handle with care! :)
(removed dash (see comments) and nearly everything :) )

Comment: Why would you `cat foo.sh -`? That will block, waiting for user to hit `ctrl-D`

Comment: Well, I'm without testable environment. Without the dash? I corrected it.

Comment: You don't need the dash, `cat` without arguments reads from standard input. But you don't need `cat` at all, and don't need the `foo.sh` file either. Just run `sh`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [runoverssh](https://github.com/yuriescl/runoverssh):

```sh
sudo apt install runoverssh
```

```sh
runoverssh -s localscript.sh user host
```

`-s` runs a local script remotely