# How to SSH into multiple servers from bash shell and provide full logins?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

This seems to be a pretty popular question, and one that has about 1,000 different answers depending on what forum you look at. Unfortunately, none work for me.

I'm trying to write a bash shell script that SSHes into a list of servers and runs a simple `stop <x> service` command to shutdown application servers on each machine.

To do this manually:

```
ssh user@server01.ourdomain.tld
user@server01.ourdomain.tld's password: ourpassword
Last login: Fri Nov 30 14:37:51 2012 from <some-ip-addr>
server01:[user@machinename ~]# (now we are SSHed in)
```

So I ask: given a set name of servers (`server01` through `server25`), how can I write a bash script to SSH into all of them and run `service ourservice stop`? This script should not require any human interaction once kicked off, and so should provide the SSH command with the appropriate password (`ourpassword`) to use. Furthermore, I need properly exit (or just close connections) after the script SSHes into each server so we don't hang resources (open connections, etc.). Thanks in advance.

Comment: might good to use /usr/bin/expect .

Comment: Usually you want to use public/private keys for automation, not passwords.

Comment: @melpomene , so How can he call `service <x> stop` on each server?.

Comment: The answer given in the comments by melpomene is obviously your best option.

Comment: your answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663679/execute-bash-script-stored-in-a-file-over-ssh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this

1. Make yourself a public/private keypair, using the `ssh-keygen` command
2. Save your private key in all of your servers, inside the `.ssh/authorized_keys` folder

Now **you can connect to any server without typing a password**, which is our first objective here.

Now you can send commands to your servers using the following syntax:

```
ssh username@serverid 'command'
```

There's a nice if short description of this [at this page](http://systemsboy.com/2006/07/send-remote-commands-via-ssh.html).

So, you just concatenate your 25 commands in a file and fire that up, like this:

```
ssh user@server1.yourservers.com 'service ourservice stop'
ssh user@server2.yourservers.com 'service ourservice stop'
```

Comment: Thanks @misterakko (+1) - if I actually want to run a shell script on each server, can you just confirm that the command would be: `ssh root@server1.yourservers.com './run-myscript.sh'`? Thanks again!

Comment: It's not a good idea to allow root login from ssh! This is fortunately turned off by default on sensible ssh servers.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Security was not a factor in the original question. Personally, I close the SSH port on my firewalls for any IP except the fixed one from my offices, so I have no fear in ssh'ing as root. As always, security means inconveniencing work, so you choose the best compromise you find.

Comment: The OP has `user` and not `root` as login. Now, you do whatever you want to do with your servers, but I'd prefer not to see a root login in an answer given to a novice user.

Comment: Anybody? Is that how I would run the script?

Comment: @HeineyBehinds Yes, but be careful. Basically, what you're doing here is opening a shell on the remote machine just for the time it takes to run the command. If your script tries to fork or fire background commands - directly or indirectly - those processes might be terminated when the mother shell is killed in a very short amount of time. These conditions can be hard to understand and debug.