# Bash script to ssh to particular server

Tags: bash, macos, ssh, terminal, scripting

I'm wondering how I would go about creating my own bash script to ssh to a server. I know it's lazy, but I would ideally want not to have to type out:

```
ssh username@server
```

And just have my own two letter command instead (i.e. no file extension, and executable from any directory).

Any help would be much appreciated. If it helps with specifying file paths etc, I am using Mac OS X.

Comment: Mac OS X is Unix, it is not Linux.

Comment: I dont understand what youre after.  You want a script to prevent you from typing 30 characters? If you are looking to just run a script inside of a ssh session, you can use the info in this thread.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663679/execute-bash-script-stored-in-a-file-over-ssh

Comment: I am looking for a script to abbreviate what I would otherwise have to write. I am not looking for running scripts inside an shh session.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set configs for ssh in file ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host dev
    HostName mydom.example.com
    User myname
```

Then, just type

```
$> ssh dev
```

And you're done. Also, you can add your public key to the file ~/.ssh/authorized_keys so you won't get prompted for your password every time you want to connect via ssh.

Answer (score 5):

Use an [alias](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html).

For example: `alias sv='ssh user@hostname'`, then you can simply type `sv`.
Be sure to put a copy of the aliases in your profile, otherwise they will disappear at the end of your session.

Comment: I have attempted this, but it says "ssh: command not found", when using the alias. This is strange as ssh works if I use it normally.

Answer (score 1):

you could create an alias like this:

`alias ss="ssh username@server"` and write it into your .bash_profile. ".bash_profile" is a hidden file is located in your home directory. If .bash_profile doesn't exist yet (check by typing `ls -a` in your home directory), you can create it yourself.

The bash_profile file will be read and executed every time you open a new shell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ssh-argv0`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/ssh-argv0/) to avoid typing `ssh`.

To do this, you need to create a link to `ssh-argv0` with the name of the host you want to connect, including the user if needed. Then you can execute that link, and `ssh` will connect you to the host of the link name.

### Example

Setup the link:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/ssh-argv0 ~/bin/my-server
```

- `/usr/bin/ssh-argv0` is the path of `ssh-argv0` on my system, yours could be different, check with `which ssh-argv0`
- I have put it in `~/bin/` to be able to execute it from any directory (in OS X you may need to add `~/bin/` manually to your path on `.bash_profile`)
- `my-server` is the name of my server, and if needed to set the user, it would be `user@my-server`

Execute it:

```
my-server
```

### Even more

You can also combine this with [mogeb answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33133020/bash-script-to-ssh-to-particular-server#33133164) to configure your server connection, so that you can call it with a shorter name, and avoid to include the user even if it is different than on the local system.

```
Host serv
    HostName my-server
    User my-user
    Port 22
```

then set a link to `ssh-argv0` with the name `serv`, and connect to it with

```
serv
```

Comment: Note that `ssh-argv0` is a [Debian extension](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=111341) replacing a capability of SSH that was removed a long time ago. it is not available on MacOS but it is [easy to roll your own](http://lost.co.nz/computing/ssh.html).