# Running full commands through remote ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, sh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to use ssh to run shell script on a remote machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine)

I am trying to make a bash script that runs on my remote server's daily cron jobs to automatically login through ssh to another unix box, run a few commands and then leave.

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh machinehost.com -l admin -p 2222 "/usr/bin/find /share/Public/backups/set0 -mtime +14 | xargs rm -f;
                               /usr/bin/find /share/Public/backups/set1 -mtime +4 | xargs rm -f;
                               /usr/bin/find /share/Public/backups/set2 -mtime +3 | xargs rm -f;
                               /usr/bin/find /share/Public/backups/set3 -mtime +21 | xargs rm -f;
                               /usr/bin/find /share/Public/backups/set4 -mtime +2 | xargs rm -f;
                               /usr/bin/find /share/Public/backups/set5 -mtime +2 | xargs rm -f;
                               "
```

The problem I am having is I need to modify my current existing code to do something a little more complicated  before each command like

```
if [ $(ls /share/Public/backups/set1 -1 | wc -l ) -gt 4 ] then run above command
fi
```

How would I go about running this command on the remote ssh machine and not on my local cron one?

Comment: @Wooble The other question was asking for a way to run a shell script on a remote computer, where as that is a solution to the problem for this poster. I think the question is different enough.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try writing your bash script locally and calling:

```
ssh user@example.com 'bash -s' < local_script.sh
```

([Found in the discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine))

Answer (score 3):

Write a script, copy it to the remote machine and from ssh run just that script.

Comment: This is the approach I use on my servers.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is to use python. There is a module called [pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html) that can solve your problem, and even more complicated scenario.