# How to connect to a remote unix box from java and run unix script in it?

Tags: java, shell, unix, remote-access

I need help in writing java code that can connect to a remote UNIX box, and run a script on that box. 
I have scoured the internet, but I have been unable to find proper documentation on how this can be accomplished.

Where is the best place to start reading about this ? What all should I know ?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ssh` is probably the best protocol to use for that sort of thing. It's more secure than `telnet` and can be set to up to use authentication keys so your code won't need to know (or ask the user) for the password to the remote box.

[Java Secure Channel (JSch)](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) is a popular pure Java implementation of the ssh protocol.

Comment: Great.. I found out about JSch and seems I can do what I wanted with it.. Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

You can use telnet and/or ssh to connect to the box. Then you can send your command, as you would do it in a terminal. Look out for a telnet/ssh implementation for java with good documentation. Telnet should be simpler, but there is no encryption. Apache has a telnet implementation: http://commons.apache.org/net/

regards
Andreas

Comment: @andreas... I need a secure connection.. Does that mean I need to use ssh and not telnet ?

Comment: Yes, you have to use ssh. Telnet is not secure.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Runtime.exec(java.lang.String)`

Comment: @michael... Can I implement a secure connection using it ??

Comment: Sure. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine