# Running a shell script on a remote server

Tags: unix, ssh, remote-server

I am trying to run a .sh script on a remote server and am getting the following error message.

Really not sure what I am doing wrong.

The command I am using is:
$ssh user@remoteserver path of file to be executed/Test.sh

Which returns the error: ksh: syntax error: `(' unexpected

Any pointers would be great :)

Comment: **You are trying to execute a script stored at a remote site.** The shell script that you are trying to execute has syntax errors. To fix this, you need to get the script code and do the necessary modifications.

Comment: I had thought this initially. But the remote script is just a simple test script and when I ran on the remote sever it worked perfectly. Hence my confusion :(

Comment: It may be something that's shell specific. Maybe the script isn't written for the k shell, which is being used to run the script.

Comment: If it is a shell-specific issue, then add the name of the shell to use to the front of the command like `bash path/to/script`, or, make sure the script has an appropriate `#!` as the first line so the correct shell is automatically selected.

Comment: I have included the #!/bin/ksh line at the beginning of the script

Comment: Again,Are you sure the script is written for the K shell?
Just do some hit and trial with some other shells. ( Bash, C)

Answer (score 2):

If Machine A is a Windows box, you can use Plink (part of PuTTY) with the -m parameter, and it will execute the local script on the remote server.

```
plink root@MachineB -m local_script.sh
```

If Machine A is a Unix-based system, you can use:

```
ssh root@MachineB 'bash -s' < local_script.sh
```

You shouldn't have to copy the script to the remote server to run it.

Source:
[How to use SSH to run a shell script on a remote machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine)