# Any way to login to the remote server and give the control back to the user?

Tags: unix

I want to write a script which could login to the remote server and give the control back to the user on the terminal so that user could execute the commands after that. It is basically to avoid a lengthy procedure to login to the server.
Please suggest me how I can do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of queries?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine

Answer (score 1):

If the remote server is running on linux, then use ssh keys for doing this job, then you'll be able to login with just one command:

```
ssh <servername>
```