# SSH connections without using password

Tags: linux

I have  two linux machines and i want to do ssh from one machine to another using some automatic scripts. But it prompts for password . Can I connect to another machine using ssh without password?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unix SSH without password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967944/unix-ssh-without-password)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are many way to go solve this problem , 
one very easy way to do is to use 
SSH -keygen where you can create public and private key and share it to the local machine/remote machine 
follow the link step by step
http://www.inertiaspeaks.com/education/ssh-without-password/

hope this helps !!