# Restart jetty remotely using SSH without it being stopped

Tags: bash, ssh, amazon-ec2, jetty

Jetty 9 is installed on EC2 linux server, jetty.sh was copied to /etc/init.d and proper links made at /etc/rc1.d, /etc/rc2.d.

I'm connecting to the instance using SSH, and running jetty through `sudo service jetty start`  which loads the service correctly, even after logging out of the SSH session.

But when running a remote SSH command `ssh -t -i key.pem ec2-user@instance.domain.com 'sudo service jetty restart'` on my instance, it starts but then stops right after. Here's the log:

```
2013-11-14 18:03:01 main DispatcherServlet [INFO] FrameworkServlet 'restapi': initialization completed in 1376 ms
2013-11-14 18:03:01.824:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@67fc3482{/,file:/usr/share/jetty/jetty-distribution-9.0.6.v20130930/webapps/ROOT/,AVAILABLE}{/ROOT}
2013-11-14 18:03:01.941:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@10614f3d{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}2013-11-14 18:03:02.226:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@666c1838{SSL-http/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8443}2013-11-14 18:03:05.670:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:Thread-3: Stopped ServerConnector@10614f3d{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2013-11-14 18:03:05.671:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:Thread-3: Stopped ServerConnector@666c1838{SSL-http/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8443}
```

I've tried executing remotely `sudo nohup service jetty restart &`, same result.

How can I restart remotely (SSH) and keep it running?

Comment: I think launching the shell allow sudo to get the user info for look it is in the sudoers file. Maybe you are already using the root account already when you log in with ssh, so using `sudo` may be useless. The other possibility it to install [expect](http://expect.nist.gov/) and look for examples [like this one](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/security/expect-ssh-login-script/ "SSH login expect shell script to supply username and password"). If those things don't work, try to look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3872762/2284570) (also please notify @ me, I don't check for answers manually).

Comment: Try running a full shell rather than just using `sudo` on its own: `ssh -t -i key.pem ec2-user@instance.example.com "sudo su - -c 'service jetty start'"`?

Comment: @pgl : "start a shell" that's the base of my comment below...

Comment: Does logging in and interactively running `sudo service jetty restart` work?

Comment: @Kof Again: When you use ssh, are you already using the root account? Do you use password or public key for ssh login?

Comment: @ishaaq: yes, it works correctly and doesn't stop when I log out.

Comment: @user2284570: no, I log in as ec2-user.

Comment: what's wrong with `ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@instance.domain.com 'sudo service jetty restart'` ? Note that I have removed `-t` from the ssh command.(presuming that current state of jetty is `running`, else the `restart` will fail eventually.)

Comment: @slayedbylucifer: it fails with `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`

Comment: yours seem to be redhat based distro. Not recommended but try this: comment out "Defaults requiretty" by running 'visudo' on target server and then run the ssh command without `-t`. It will display password in clear text. This is not recommended, but could try this for testing purpose so we will know whether it's `ssh` issue or `sudo` issue

Comment: @slayedbylucifer: it fails loading, in the log it says: `2013-11-14 12:41:15.581:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED SslSelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8443: java.net.BindException: Address already in use`, I guess that it requires more su permissions

Comment: @Kof have you tried `nohup`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Solution:

1. On EC2 instance, edit the sudoers file with what you want.
2. Then, restart Jetty remotely with this command: ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@instance.domain.com 'sudo service jetty restart', notice that -t was removed.
3. If command prompt doesn't come back after restart finishes, add a >/dev/null at the end.

Answer (score 2):

I replicated your issue on CentOS (RPM based) and it works like a charm. I installed jetty and configured it on port 7070.

**Stopping Jetty:**

```
# ssh -t -i key.pem ec2-user@ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com 'sudo service jetty stop'
Stopping Jetty: OK
Connection to ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com closed.
```

**Nothing is listening on port 7070:**

```
# ssh -t -i key.pem ec2-user@ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com 'sudo netstat -anp | grep 7070'
Connection to ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com closed.
```

**Starting jetty:**

```
# ssh -t -i key.pem ec2-user@ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com 'sudo service jetty start'
Starting Jetty: . OK Thu Nov 14 08:57:19 EST 2013
Connection to ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com closed.
```

**port 7070 is in use now:**

```
# ssh -t -i key.pem ec2-user@ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com 'sudo netstat -anp | grep 7070'
tcp        0      0 :::7070                     :::*                        LISTEN      2431/java           
Connection to ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com closed.
```

**Here are the corresponding logs:**

```
2013-11-14 08:57:15.610:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.h.MovedContextHandler@1c9c8aa{/oldContextPath,null,AVAILABLE}
2013-11-14 08:57:16.283:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@176982e{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:7070}
2013-11-14 08:57:16.392:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@166320b{SSL-http/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8443}
```

**And here is the platform I used:**

```
# ssh -t -i key.pem ec2-user@ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com 'sudo lsb_release -a'
LSB Version:    :core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-ia32:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-ia32:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 6.3 (Final)
Release:    6.3
Codename:   Final
Connection to ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com closed.
```

**And finally, here is hte `restart` command:**

```
# ssh -t -i key.pem ec2-user@ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com 'sudo service jetty restart'
Stopping Jetty: OK
Starting Jetty: . OK Thu Nov 14 09:13:00 EST 2013
Connection to ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com closed.
```

I ran all above commands via `sudo` to make sure that sudo is not the issue.

- Were there any changes on your instance?
- Were you able to start jetty via SSH n sudo in the past successfully? if yes, then what has changed since then?
- If this is new installation, then spin-up a new instance and check whether you still face the same issue.

BTW, I am not a java guy and followed [these](http://kukunotes.wordpress.com/2013/01/21/eclipse-jetty-9-0-installation-on-centos-6-3/) instruction to install jetty 9.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply, but what you offer is what I tried in the first place. It probably worked on your instance because it's Centos, mine is Linux (see org post). Like I said, it looks OK when running the SSH command, but port isn't open after SHH connection is closed and logs shows Jetty was stopped (see org post for log).

Comment: @Kof : Linux on Amazon ec2 use red hat and I've seen this:[`With Red Hat Cloud Access, customers have the ability to use the advantages provided by public cloud providers, while continuing to benefit from the high level of support delivered directly by Red Hat.`](http://www.redhat.com/promo/amazon/) I don't understand why you didn't got help form their support...

Answer (score 1):

I think that the init script teminate before Jetty is fully launched so it still need the shell during some seconds after the script termination.
Just try:

```
ssh -t -i key.pem ec2-user@instance.domain.com 'sh -c "sudo service jetty restart;sleep 8"'
```

Again, you may try to [redirect input from your script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3872762/2284570)

```
ssh -t -i key.pem ec2-user@instance.domain.com <<'FIN'
#commands to run on remote host
/bin/bash --login -i -s << FAIM
su -l -s /bin/bash << FEIN
your_password
nohup service jetty restart &
bg
disown -a
sleep 20
FEIN
sleep 5
FAIM
FIN
```

An another alternative is to ask to the red hat support, since you're paying for it with your Amazon cloud service.

Comment: This produced the same result, only with 8 seconds between the 'Started' message to 'Stopped' message. Jetty stops once SSH session is closed.

Comment: @Kof And for the second one? Since it consist of redirecting /dev/stdin (no sh -c), it think it should work as when you log in manually.

Comment: Result: `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.` `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`

Comment: @Kof comment out `Default requiretty` in the sudoers file

Comment: @user2284580: Thank you - that last clue did help. Removing `requiretty` allowed running SSH command without `-t` parameter, which caused `ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@instance.domain.com 'sudo service jetty restart' >/dev/null` to work. Notice that without `>/dev/null`, I would not get command prompt back. Thanks to Artur R. Czechowski for this suggestion. Please update your answer with the right solution (removing `requiretty`, removing `-t` and redirecting output to null) and I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to redirect I/O using following command:

```
ssh -t -i key.pem ec2-user@instance.domain.com 'sudo service jetty restart </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/dev/null'
```

If it helps, you can try with only >/dev/null.

Comment: Still the same. Jetty stops once session is closed.

Answer (score 0):

try this , use -f to force ssh into background :

```
 ssh -f -t -i key.pem ec2-user@instance.domain.com 'sudo service jetty restart'
```

Comment: It doesn't do the restart, instead it writes: `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo` - there's a conflict between -f and -t, which forces pseudo-tty allocation.

Comment: create a bash script on instance.domain.com and instead of sudo … run the script

Comment: Impossible, because ec2-user doesn't have the required permissions. Jetty failed loading when I tried due to file access errors, etc.

Comment: @Kof michael mean create the script manually while logged in on the server...

Comment: @user2284570: Understood that, that's what I did - Jetty fails loading because it doesn't have permissions for some resources.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work, from my comment above:

```
ssh -t -i key.pem ec2-user@instance.example.com "sudo su - -c 'service jetty start'"
```

?

Comment: Tried that just now, same issue - it stops as soon as the SSH connection is closed.