# how to execute if else condition with ssh to remote server

Tags: shell, unix, ssh

I am using following script to remote connection to a server and then if connection is successful then echoing success and if success then trying to sudo a file 
.If connection failed then it should echo FAIL. e.g

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh -t -t rxapp@$1
'if [$? -eq 0 ];
then
echo "SUCCESS"
sudo /etc/init/ntp $2
else
echo "FAIL: Couldnot connect to remote server"
fi'
```

Here $1 and $2 are given on command line .
But this is not getting successful.Script only doing successful ssh but not running sudo and other echo commands.
Output :
Successful SSH but one exiting it showing following

```
./jenkins_ucf.sh: line 9: if [$? -eq 0 ];
then
echo "SUCCESS"
sudo /etc/init.d/unifiedCommFwk $2
else
echo "FAIL: COuldnot connect to remote server"
fi: No such file or directory
```

ANy help please ? or any alternative to it will be helpful too.

Comment: Why the single quotes? `if [.......`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh -t -t rxapp@$1 "echo SUCCESS; /etc/init/ntp $2" || echo "FAIL: Could not connect to remote server"
```

or with `if`:

```
if ssh -t -t rxapp@$1 "echo SUCCESS; /etc/init/ntp $2"; then
    echo SUCCESS
else
    echo "FAIL: Could not connect to remote server"
fi
```

You need to separate the parts that run on the remote server upon successful connection from the parts that run locally when the connection fails.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need '  ' instead if you are trying to use backticks - that is not required either.

try this :

```
ssh -t -t rxapp@$1
if [ $? -eq 0 ];
then
echo "SUCCESS"
sudo /etc/init/ntp $2
else
echo "FAIL: Couldnot connect to remote server"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute an if else condition against an SSH server like so:

```
ssh user@host 'bash -s' <<'ENDSSH'
if [ someCommand ];
then
  echo "SUCCESS"
else
  echo "FAIL"
fi'
ENDSSH
```

Basically pulled [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7363641/26510)

Answer (score -2):

Simply do

```
ssh host -l username "if yourcommand; then echo Success; else echo Failure;fi"
```

For example

```
#!/bin/bash
CMD="if $1; then echo Success; else echo Failure; fi"
ssh host -l user "$CMD"
```