# Alias to launch a command right after ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I'd like to have an alias to run a command right after login through ssh on a computer, basically doing the following:

```
$ ssh my_server
$ bash
```

Because I always want to use the bash terminal once logged in.
One stone, two birds; that would save me some time considering how much I'm using it.

Thank you.

Edit: I found that the following works:

```
 $ ssh my_server -t bash
```

Comment: Why don't you change your info in `/etc/passwd`? `usermod -s /bin/bash <your_user>`

Comment: @devnull: It doesn't work, maybe because I still need to enter my password when logging through ssh. I'll try to automatize this and will let you know. Thanks.

Comment: I was tempted to think that you wanted to execute `bash` once you exit `ssh`.  Seems like you need what @fedorqui suggested.

Comment: If you want to change the shell on the terminal go for fedorqui's proposal.

Comment: @fedorqui Is it a command I should run on the server? Because I get `usermod: command not found`

Comment: @devnull I added the ssh-keygen but it still isn't working

Comment: Ok, I just found that `ssh my_server -t bash` works just fine.

Comment: @Liam this is a command just superusers can use, so you need `sudo` permissions for that.

Comment: Normal users use `chsh` (change shell) to change their shell.

Answer (score 0):

You want `ssh -t hostname bash -li` to get an interactive login shell

Comment: Not working, strangely it even rejects my password when trying this.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following:

To execute one command:

```
ssh user@host ls or ssh -t user@host
```

where -t: Force pseudo-tty allocation.

To execute a script:

```
ssh user@host 'bash -s' < localscript.sh
```

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine)

Comment: In my case, `-t` alone is not enough I need to add `bash` to get what I want. Thank you for the input ;)