# Run script in remote machine from a ruby script

Tags: ruby, ssh, command

Inside my ruby script I need to run a script sh which is located in another machine (opening an ssh connection?) and then continues with my program.
So:

- my ruby script (e.g: Machine 10.1.1.2)

  generic command
  generic command 
  ...
  RUN SCRIPT *UPDATE.SH* ON MACHINE 10.1.1.15
  generic command
  generic command

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I'm trying to understand if it is feasible and how can I do that. So, now I have nothing concrete. I think I need to use Net::SSH or something similar... but no idea, this is the first time

Comment: I don't know anything at all about Ruby, but I do know it's certainly easy to remotely execute a command.  Even if you have to do something stupid like make a system call, rather than using some built-in functionality ruby has, it shouldn't be too difficult: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine

Comment: on what OS are you ? there are command line utilities like psexec.exe on windows to do that

Comment: Have you seen sshkit? https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md