# how to login on remote server using ssh (trough shell scripting)

Tags: shell, expect

I would like ask your regarding my script where i am not able to automate login though ssh.

```
set timeout 30
/usr/bin/ssh -p 8484 root@192.168.210.210
expect 
{
   "root@192.168.210.210s password" 
   {
      send "Passw0rd\r" 
   }
}
```

Comment: Hello, didn't you forget ":" as in password: ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use ssh to run shell script on a remote machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine)

Answer (score 0):

- `spawn` is missing with your command: `spawn /usr/bin/ssh -p 8484       root@192.168.210.210`
- `expect` doesn't expect the `{` to be on the next line; write `expect {` instead.
- A `'` seems to be missing: `"root@192.168.210.210's password"`