# SSH execute command from txt file one by one

Tags: ssh, wget, execute

I have a text file which which contain sets of ssh commands.
How can I execute those commands in ssh? and get command executed one by one?

my file name is: `urllist.txt`
Inside `urllist.txt` I have following commands:

```
wget -O file1.f url1
wget -O file2.f url2
wget -O file3.f url3
# about thousands of links.
```

How can I execute them one by one in ssh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and make your text file a script, made for executing those commands on the remote machine.

In order to run that script in a remote ssh session, you can refer to "[how to use ssh to run shell script on a remote machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2732991/6309)"

If the rmeote machine is a Unix one:

```
ssh root@MachineB 'bash -s' < local_script.sh
```

A more complete solution would use the [python (client side) tool Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/0.9.3/).