# Shell script - SSH

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I am using shell script to add some file to server. Is there any way to write a shell script that will execute one part on local computer and the other part when you're logged into that server?

For example, I want to log in, do something, add some file, and then I want to list everything on that server.

ssh something@something

I enter password

Then list files from server.

Comment: You can append the command to run onto the ssh command as in `ssh user@host ls /remote/dir/on/host` Couple that with an SSH key, and the action is basically seamless as though you executed it locally.

Comment: I personally use Yarek's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a command to end of the ssh command; for example:

```
ssh username@host ls
```

will run `ls` on the server, instead of giving you a login shell.