# How to run bash script with commands in tests in vagrant?

Tags: python, linux, bash, vagrant

Running commands or script lines with simple tests, like `-e`, in `vagrant` using the `ssh` subcommand works fine (e.g.

```
vagrant ssh -c 'if ! [ -e file.deb ] ; then wget http://a.b/file.deb; fi'
```

as soon as string comparison and command execution `bash` quoting gets involved, complexity immediately rises to the sky. I tried

- escaping strings, but that doesn't seem to work in general (complexity of escaping of escaping of escaping ... in `bash` is just inacceptable)
- writing everything in a script file with `cat <<EOF > file [code]EOF` idiom, e.g.

  ```
  vagrant ssh -c 'cat <<EOF > fetch.sh \
  #!/bin/bash \
  if [ "$(md5sum file.deb | cut -d \" \" -f 1)" != "d757d51819f8f945ae7715b532ab8d2e" ] ; then wget http://a/b/file.deb; fi \
  EOF'
  vagrant ssh -c 'bash ./fetch.sh'
  ```

  causes `` ./fetch.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `if' ``
- the failure of the `cat EOF` idiom implies failure of any sort of script created in `vagrant` (`python`, `groovy`, etc. would suffer from the same incapacity of `bash` to provide usable string quoting/be usable at all)

Is there any way to execute script code with complex statements in tests inside a `vagrant` box? Do I seriously need to transfer the script via the localhost interface (using FTP or something similar)?

Answer (score 0):

With knowledge of  [How to use SSH to run a shell script on a remote machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine) it's possible to connect to vagrant using

```
ssh -p [port] -i [keyfile] vagrant@localhost 'bash -s' < script.sh
```

(with `[port]` and `[keyfile]` retrieved from `vagrant ssh-config`) and the script code put in `script.sh`.

The port can change if multiple `vagrant` instances are running (each starting its own SSH server), so you might need to parse `vagrant ssh-config`.