# Open SSH tunnel via Plink and run R Scripts via command line batch file

Tags: batch-file, ssh, cmd, plink

I am trying to open an SSH tunnel via Plink in the command line to run a few R scripts and I cannot get the R scripts to run and when they do run the tunnel was not created, so the connection to my database crashes.

The Plink code looks like this:

```
plink.exe -ssh [username]@[hostname] -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 -i "[SSH key]" -N
```

Followed by the code to run the R scripts

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.1\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH qidash.R
```

I cannot seem to get the tunnel to stay open to run the R script. However, I can open the tunnel separately and run the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have the two commands in a batch-file one after another like:

```
plink.exe -ssh [username]@[hostname] -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 -i "[SSH key]" -N
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.1\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH qidash.R
```

Then indeed the `R.exe` is never executed as the `plink.exe` runs indefinitely.

---

You have to run the commands in parallel:

- You can use `start` command to run `plink.exe` in the background.
- Use `killtask` command to kill the background `plink` process after the `R.exe` finishes.
- You should probably also pause a little before you run `R.exe` to allow the Plink to establish the tunnel.

```
rem Open tunnel in the background
start plink.exe -ssh [username]@[hostname] -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 -i "[SSH key]" -N

rem Wait a second to let Plink establish the tunnel 
timeout /t 1

rem Run the task using the tunnel
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.1\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH qidash.R

rem Kill the tunnel
taskkill /im plink.exe
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked great.