# Send shell script to linux machine remotely

Tags: linux, shell

I have a web application that generates a shell script with commands running on a server.

Then I also have another Linux server where the script should be executed.

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction in terms of how I could send a shell script from one server to another linux server and execute it on the second server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use scp to transfer the file over

```
scp <source_file> <destination>
```

if your destination is the host in question:

```
scp myfile.sh username@x.x.x.x:/path/to/new/script.sh
```

For executing on the server, you have various options.  You can use a cron job to execute it periodically.  You can use rc.local to execute at startup.  You can use ssh.

Lets take SSH as an example:

```
ssh username@x.x.x.x 'sh /path/to/script.sh'
```

The above ssh command will run myfile.txt on the server.

Answer (score 0):

for linux machines easiest way is

```
ssh root@MachineB 'bash -s' < local_script.sh
```

as explained in [Jason R. Coombs's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine)