# How to copy files and folders from one remote server to another remote server using scp command?

Tags: linux, terminal, remote-access, scp, remote-server

I'm using **Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS** on my machine.

There are two remote servers viz.

- 64.211.219.95
- 42.11.37.153

I can log in to both servers using ssh command. Both the servers have username **root**.

Now I want to **copy** all the files and folders present in folder **'/var/www/'** from server **64.211.219.95** to the folder **'/var/www/project_dir/'** on server **'42.11.37.153'** remotely i.e. using **scp command**.

How should I do it? What should be the exact command without any syntactical error I've to use to make this operation working?

Please somebody help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I understand both directories are on the same server, thus [you don't need scp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine).

Comment: @Emilien:No, both directories are on different servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that your problem is with specifying a wildcard.  You can avoid this difficulty using a recursive copy from a directory with a trailing slash, vis:

```
scp -r root@64.211.219.95:/var/www/ root@42.11.37.153:/var/www/project_dir
```

The `scp` command can be run from any server you like, not restricted to the source or destination machine.

Comment: Both directories are on different servers. Could you please modify your answer accordingly. Also let me know on which server I've to get login to run the scp command.

Comment: To which server I should log in using ssh and run the command you given?

Comment: You can run this from any server - one of the two you have mentioned or any other you like.

Comment: Don't I need to use /var/www/* to copy all contents present in folder www?

Comment: I would be very careful about using `*` as it is would need to be passed to the remote machine before expansion.  The `-r` sidesteps the problem.  Be careful to append `/` to the source directory to avoid copying the directory itself.

Answer (score 1):

Login at server 64.211.219.95 and use:

```
scp -r /var/www root@42.11.37.153:/var/www/project_dir
```

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, depending on your solution and infrastructure, you probably would like to ***synchronize*** your source_dir with remote_dir, still using SSH secure and fast protocol. This way you don't need to copy WHOLE package, but only what is necessary(changes).

In this case, what you want is ***rsync***:

```
rsync -Cravgtzp --delete --exclude="*.gz" -e ssh user@source_host:source_dir/ user@remote_host:remote_dir/ >> /tmp/logfile.log
```

Note:

`--delete` is used when you want to delete files within remote_dir when they have been deleted within source_dir.

`--exclude` is used when you don't have interest in copying those files (supposing *.gz are temporary files fix example)..