# ssh and run command from remote computer doesn't pass control

Tags: ssh

I followed the example from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine) to create the heredoc below:

```
ssh -t -t me@abc.xxx.com <<'ENDSSH'
cd my_dir
myprog arg1 arg2
ENDSSH
```

This will ssh into the remote machine and launch a program with a couple arguments.  The issue is, when I am done using myprog, pressing control+C exits the entire ssh session instead of just quitting myprog.

How can I adjust my heredoc so it acts the same way as if I just typed those commands in manually?

Comment: You can't directly. Local signals target local processes. You cannot send a signal to a remote process. You'd have to implement a message broker or bus system or similar for that. But what for? Why is killing the ssh process such an issue if it only saves that single purpose anyway?

Comment: or look at running `screen` inside of your remote `ssh` connection. Good luck.