# Remote execute script on Linux

Tags: linux, shell

Wondering if it is possible to write a shell script like this, and if possible, any reference/sample implementation I can refer to? Thanks.

- Step 1, scp a local file on a local box to a remote box ABC, may need
  input password or we can hard code password into script possible?
- Step 2, remote execute a script on box ABC, and leverage the file
  uploaded in Step 1
- Step 3, the output of Step 2 (which is on
  console/stdout) is redirected to local box.

I tried this:

```
scp ~/Downloads/data/1.dat root@host:/root/data /root/exercise/test /root/data/1.dat
```

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/ ?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, I just want to write a distributed (cross multiple boxes) automated test script. If I need to rephrase my question, please advise. Thanks.

Comment: nah, I was just wondering whether you're looking for a configuration management tool.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use ssh to run shell script on a remote machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine)

Comment: @JoaoVitorino, thanks for the great reference. Tried the method but it does not fully work for me and your advice is appreciated. The confusion is, I need to execute scp first which should be executed locally and then run command "test" on remote box. How to distinguish between local/remote in my scenario? Thanks. Here is the code 

`scp ~/Downloads/data/1.dat root@host:/root/data
/root/exercise/test /root/data/1.dat`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, thanks for the advice. I just need simple script in my case to reduce overhead. I just my further issues above and your advice is appreciated. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to copy a file to a remote machine, run a command there with that file as an argument and get the output on your local machine. Apparently, you need the `test` program, which is on the remote machine.

Your try takes you halfway there. You could do it as follows:

```
scp ~/Downloads/data/1.dat root@host:/root/data
ssh root@host '/root/exercise/test /root/data/1.dat'
```

The first command copies your file, the second runs the command on the remote machine. Depending on the `test` command, you can new get some output file back to your local machine:

```
scp root@host:/root/results/outputfile .
```

Or, if the command writes to standard out, you could redirect the output to a file on the remote machine by appending `> /root/results/outputfile` to the ssh command and then scp it back to your local machine.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin for the reply, mark your reply as answered. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can execute commands using `ssh`, for example:

```
$ ssh user@host ls -la
```

will connect to host `host` as `user`, and after successful authorization execute `ls -la` command, presenting the output locally. After command finishes connection will be closed.

Comment: Thanks nsilent22, I can change "ls -la" to a shell script?

Comment: Thanks nsilent22 , tried your method but it does not work for me and your advice is appreciated. The confusion is, I need to execute scp first which should be executed locally and then run command "test" on remote box. How to distinguish between local/remote in my scenario? Thanks. Here is the code 

`scp ~/Downloads/data/1.dat root@host:/root/data
/root/exercise/test /root/data/1.dat`

Comment: @LinMa: Just do `ssh root@host /root/exercise/test /root/data/1.dat` after you `scp` your file. Of course - make sure `test` has proper execution permissions.