# Executing multi level shell script and get response from remote machine

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, remote-access

I have two shell scripts like

**mem.sh**

```
RESULT=$(awk {print} /proc/meminfo)
r="$(./test.sh)"
RESULT="$RESULT$r"
echo ${RESULT#* }
exit ${RESULT%% *}
```

**test.sh**

```
echo "HI"
```

When I execute mem.sh locally it will print memory info followed by HI without any error, but I am in need of executing that script in remote machine, I am doing it like below

```
cat mem.sh | ssh user@ip  >> result.txt
```

I am getting error like

```
unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I could't find solution, Please help me on this or Is there any way to do this?

Question #2: Is there any way to execute multiple shell scripts(available in local machine) in remote machine?

I am using linux machine.

Comment: look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine

Comment: You can't run local scripts on a remote machine without sending them to the remote machine.

Comment: You get that error for that *exact* script? What shell is default on the remote host? Try a simpler script and see if you can get working correctly. Then try commenting out lines in `mem.sh` until you figure out which is broken (though none of them look like they are to me). Your `exit` command is broken however in that it will not provide `exit` with a numeric value.

Comment: Yes! @EtanReisner, I have tried without exit also. It gives same response.

Comment: Yes, `exit` isn't causing the quote problem it is just *another* problem with your script. Can you show the output of `hexdump -C mem.sh`?