# How to connect and run shell script on remote server, via shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I hardly know anything about shell script or terminal commands.

**Want to achieve:**

Make a shell script, that connects to remote server and after connecting to that server, run some commands on that server.

Is it possible?

I have tried googling, but didn't find something, i am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using ssh (secure shell), you can refer this question for answers [How to use SSH to run a shell script on a remote machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine)

Answer (score 1):

```
/tmp/sh.sh  is shell script on remote server.

#!/bin/bash
ssh "root@server-ip" 'sh -c "( (nohup /tmp/sh.sh) )"'    

#use following for suppressing the output from remote server script.
ssh "root@server-ip" 'sh -c "( (nohup /tmp/sh.sh &>/dev/null ) & )"'
```

Comment: i have one doubt, don't we need any kind of password, as i am connecting to other server. means in your code no password is mentioned?

Comment: @sandeepKumar Set up ssh with private key.