# Does Scilab have a Server version available?

Tags: server, scilab

Could anyone please tell if Scilab has a Server version so tasks may be executed by running Scilab from 1 central location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your usecase.

If you have a high perfomance server that you want to perform the calculations, scilab has a `scilab-cli` mode which you could start remotely over ssh (as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2732991/1149326). See description on [`--no-gui`](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.0/en_US/scilab.html) flag in documentation.

If you want a more interactive session running on a server, (so people don't have to install scilab locally), take a look at the efforts to [make a scilab kernel that integrates into jupyter notebooks](https://github.com/Calysto/scilab_kernel).
You can see an example Scilab Jupyter notebook [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/calysto/scilab_kernel/blob/master/scilab_kernel.ipynb).