# Copy Files via SSH, but changing remote user after login

Tags: python, bash, shell, scripting, server

The situation is simple:

I can ssh to a remote server with `ssh my_remote_user@remote_server`, and would like copy some files, i.e. `/var/www/docs/web.config.txt` to local.

The problem is that `/var/www/docs/web.config.txt` has ownership like `userA:userA`. I can access as this user via

`$ su - userA
$ Password: userApwd`

with this in mind, I can:

1 - copy `/var/www/docs/web.config.txt` to `/tmp` folder and change ownership to `my_remote_user`
2 - copy from remote to local from remote `/tmp` dir

#### MY QUESTION:

Via `bash`, `python` or other language can I automatize this steps?

> NB: with `expect` it seems I can `su - userA` and then insert the password in remote server, but subsequent commands like `cp /var/www/docs/web.config.txt` doesn't occurs...

Thanks

Comment: Also, you can look on this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-a-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use SCP commands if you are on Linux server, following is sample command.

scp user@host:directory/SourceFile TargetFile
scp -r user@host:directory/SourceFolder TargetFolder

Comment: I know `scp`, but my problem is that in remote machine I need to change user in order to copy the files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `su` with a parameter `-c` to run arbitrary command, i.e.:

```
su -c "scp /var/www/docs/web.config.txt your_user@client_machine:" userA
```

Comment: Sorry, my explanation could be not clear... I need to copy files from remote server to local, and in remote server I need to change the user. I can't invert , that is running scp in remote in order to copy to local. Furthemore my problem is how automatize the user changing...

Comment: Using `su -c` on a remote server and, then run on a remote server (under `su` command).

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use scp and userA credentials to login to the remote server, i.e. instead of:

```
scp my_remote_user@remote_server:/remote/dir local_dir
```

use:

```
scp userA@remote_server:/remote/dir local_dir
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, too much time is passed!

Thank for all reply, but at the end I've found the answer using `expect` but in different manner I had supposed...

To be clear, I have to run an `expect script` but only in my localhost, while I thought to run expect into remote server...

The following is my script, hoping helpful for someone:

## 1 Parametric Script

say `remoteActions.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --

set timeout -1

# ssh connection
spawn ssh $env(fsUser)@$env(fsHost)
expect "password:"
send "$env(fsPass)\r"
expect "sh"

# switch to apache user
send "su - apache\r"
expect "Password: "
send "$env(fsApachePass)\r"
expect -re ".*apache.*"


# create folder if not exists
send "\[ -d /tmp/$env(fsRemoteTmpDir) \] || mkdir -m 777 -p /tmp/$env(fsRemoteTmpDir)\r"
expect -re ".*apache.*"

# copy folder via rsync but exclude some dirs
send "rsync -a $env(fsExcludeFromRemoteDir) $env(fsRemoteDir) /tmp/$env(fsRemoteTmpDir)\r"
expect -re ".*apache.*"


# change permissions
send "chmod -R 777 /tmp/$env(fsRemoteTmpDir)\r"

expect -re ".*apache.*"
send "exit\r\n"
```

## 2 Real Script with configurations

```
#!/bin/bash

### File System
export fsUser='sshuser'
export fsHost='remoteip'
export fsPass='remotepass'
export fsApachePass='apache'
export fsRemoteDir='/var/www/webapp'
export fsExcludeFromRemoteDir='--exclude=img/ --exclude=upload/'
export fsRemoteTmpDir='/bak'


# copy remote folder into remote directory
./remoteActions.sh
```

## 3 My Trick

with this script I can access with my standard user to `{fsRemoteTmpDir}`, which now has 777 permissions, so I have still two actions to do:

1. run `scp` to copy from remote to local
2. via `ssh` command or with another `expect` script to delete the remote `{fsRemoteTmpDir}`

I don't post `1` and `2` because the heart of my question/answer is in `remoteActions.sh`.

Thank you guys!!!