# Run a set of command on deployment server after bitbucket pipeline push?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have setup bitbucket pipeline to push updates on the staging server when a commit is made. I am using `git ftp` for that.

On the next step I need to run various command on the deployment (staging) server in order to run the app properly after the push.

For example:

1. `composer install`
2. `php artisan db:seed`
3. `php artisan migrate`

.. and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your staging server is on a Cloud Service like AWS then you could use AWS CodeDeploy via a python-script using boto for the same. Or in case you use something else, whatever the equivalent that would be. Deployment guides at https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/build-test-and-deploy-with-pipelines-792496469.html has more relevant details.

In case your server is an on-premise server (and UNIX based) you could use a ssh key-pair to execute commands on the server like:

```
ssh -i xyz.pem user1@server1 'command -args'
ssh -i xyz.pem user1@server1 'command -args'
```

Comment: Staging server is not in AWS its on a VPS. ssh command execution seems to be right way to go.

Answer (score 4):

You can you try to add a step to run a shell script by ssh.

`$ ssh user@host.example "ls -la"`

in your case,

`$ ssh user@host.example "php artisan db:seed"`

You can find further ways to run here:
[How to use SSH to run a shell script on a remote machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-a-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine)

And regarding composer step, you can add in your receipe:

`curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer`

`composer install --no-interaction --no-progress --prefer-dist`