# How to run cluster initialization script on GCP after creation of cluster

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-platform, presto

I have created a Google Dataproc cluster, but need to install presto as I now have a requirement. Presto is provided as an initialization action on Dataproc [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/blob/master/presto/presto.sh), how can I run this initialization action after creation of the cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most init actions would probably run even after the cluster is created (though I haven't tried the Presto init action).

I like to run `clusters describe` to get the instance names, then run something like `gcloud compute ssh <NODE> -- -T sudo bash -s < presto.sh` for each node. Reference: [How to use SSH to run a shell script on a remote machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-a-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine).

Notes:

- Everything after the `--` are args to the normal ssh command
- The `-T` means don't try to create an interactive session (otherwise you'll get a warning like "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.")
- I use "sudo bash" because init actions scripts assume they're being run as root.
- presto.sh must be a copy of the script on your local machine. You could alternatively ssh and `gsutil cp gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/presto/presto.sh . && sudo bash presto.sh`.

But @Kanji Hara is correct in general. Spinning up a new cluster is pretty fast/painless, so we advocate using initialization actions when creating a cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **initialization-actions** parameter

**Ex**:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create $CLUSTERNAME \
    --project $PROJECT \
    --num-workers $WORKERS \
    --bucket $BUCKET \
    --master-machine-type $VMMASTER \
    --worker-machine-type $VMWORKER \
    --initialization-actions \
         gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/presto/presto.sh \
    --scopes cloud-platform
```

Maybe this script can help you: https://github.com/kanjih-ciandt/script-dataproc-datalab

Comment: I already have a cluster created, I cant tear it down, so I need to run the initialization action on an existing cluster. But your answer suggests creating new cluster

Comment: Ok I got.. So you could access the master and works and execute presto.sh script.  (Get script using gsutil cp  gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/presto/presto.sh <path>).