# Need to execute a shell script in different unix servers

Tags: shell, unix

There is a script in different unix servers for space cleanup.
I dont want to connect all servers everytime, and want to run the script by connecting to only one unix server.
Can you please assist on it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest 4 different ways of doing it,

**1.** The easiest way **:**  configure space cleanup script in `crontab`

**2.** Call script in remote servers from one server via `ssh`. see this link [how-to-use-ssh-to-run-a-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-a-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine)

**3.** Run a `script` which keep on looking for a `status/trigger file` ( a dummy file) in some location, push the dummy file (ftp,scp etc) from one servers to that specific location whenever required.

**4.** Have a `http server-client` set up , may be a `cgi script`, which can be triggered via http request.

There could be many other ways. I have tried all above and all will work,