# Unable to use Ksu access in Jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

My userid has been given ksu access to root level.
so when I login to unix account with my id and do ksu it moves me to a root level.

I want to use this in Jenkins through "execute shell script on remote host using ssh".

Can some one help me on how to use ksu command here ?

Comment: You may use this link 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-a-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine'

Comment: What i need to do here is : first login from my user id, then type command ksu, it asks for a password(root passwrd), once you give that it logins to the system as root