# How to use a while loop in which a file is passed for iteration in ssh?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, automation

I want to perform an operation where I am passing a file ( let's name it X ) in the "while loop" in an ssh command.

For an example:

```
ssh -n root@host "<<here I want to fit in my below while loop>>"

while read line
do
    cd $line
    cp file1 /location2/
done < X.txt
```

I hope you understand that I want a single line while loop here in my ssh command.

Please help me out.

Comment: Where is `X.txt` located (remote or local)? Where did you mean `cd` and `cp` have to be done?

Comment: what is the purpose of reading a line in the while loop if you're not doing anything with the line in the do? in any case, have you taken a look at this? https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-howto-read-line-by-line-from-file/

Comment: to write multiple commands in a single line, split them with a `;`. Or, save your while loop to a `script.sh` file on the host machine, and run it that way.

Comment: @F.Hauri , the X.txt is located at remote only. That is why I want to pass this while loop as a command in the ssh statement to run on host that I am trying to connect.

Comment: I have edited my code @cptwonton . And, now you can see the $line is a directory name. X.txt contains the list of directories. I am using $line with cd command.

Comment: @cptwonton , I have tried separating multiple commands by splitting them with ; but I how to use that in a single line while loop. I am not able to understand that.

Though, saving the while loop in a script on remote host sounds good, I will give it a try.

Comment: and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-a-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine

Comment: The method of putting my while loop in a separate script and running the same remotely actually worked. My issue is resolved. Thank you so much @cptwonton