# How to do an ssh and execute a shell script's function remotely

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script `test.sh` and I am trying to ssh and call that scrip't function in the same script:

```
#!/bin/sh

testme()
{
   echo "hello world"
}

ssh myserver "/opt/scripts/test.sh; testme"
```

But I keep getting `testme command not found`

What is the correct way of calling a function from a script after ssh?

Comment: have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/305035/2055887

Comment: You need to *source* the script, not execute it, so that the function is defined in the current shell.

Comment: Also, is the script actually *on* the remote host, or just the local host? In general, you can't "send" function definitions over the `ssh` connection.

Comment: try ssh remoteServer '/bin/bash -x -s ' < <(cat /path/on/local/server/test.sh; echo "testme")

Answer (score 1):

If you use Bash on both sides, you can have it serialize the function for you:

```
#!/bin/bash

testme()
{
   echo "hello world"
}

ssh myserver "$(declare -f testme); testme"
```

If you need `sh` compatibility, this is not an option.