# how to run pm2 in spawn process remotely from another server, not a shell script problem

Tags: ssh, child-process

> this is not a problem related to shell script , this a problem on how to restart or use pm2 commands from spawn process in nodejs from a remote server. running the pm2 commands solo or in a shell script directly on the server , it works fine , but when i use spawn i get the error below.

how to restart pm2, using spawn process , using `ssh root@ip`

i've tried this

```
ssh root@ip 'pm2 restart all'
```

but when i try this on my local pc directly from my terminal 
it works , but when i try to run it in exces or spawn process , i get this error  `bash: pm2: command not found failed with code 127`

i also tried , putting my commands in `script.sh` 
and send it with this command from **spawn**

```
scp /root/script.sh root@${ip}:/root&&ssh root@${ip} bash script.sh
```

i get the same error. but if i run alone in terminal it works , is the error in environment variable , it's not loaded correctly when i run it in spawn prcess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use SSH to run a shell script on a remote machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-a-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine)

Comment: @O.Jones this is not a problem in running sell script on another machine , please read the question very carefully , i asked that the problem in spawn process , not in sell script , because i already run it using script.sh and terminal directly , but when i run it with spawn process , the problem occurs

Comment: What happens if you use `ssh root@ip` to get a shell on the remote machine, and then issue the command `pm2 restart all` ? I bet it doesn't work. I bet `pm2` can't be found in the `PATH` available to the root user on the remote machine. I *know* running `pm2` from root is a bad choice for security reasons.

Comment: @O.Jones i don't want to make a user with root privileges , my question was a problem in spawn process , do i need to load en variables when i run the spawn ? or where is the problem exactly , this is vps server and when i log in i use pm2 command and it works , so why it didn't work when i used only spawn all other commands works just fine, so please tell me exactly what's the error . or how to solve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ssh -t root@ip "export PATH='path/to/pm2'; pm2 restart all"
```

You should include the pathname to pm2 even if it is the current directory (eg ./pm2 or /path/to/pm2) to ensure it is found, or else export PATH=.... before the call to pm2.

Comment: it didn't work
i get this error `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.` and bash pm2 command not found also the same error as before and when i use -tt i get connection close

Comment: The exact same command works for me. I use it every day. Could you check your network firewall setting or the server has to be accessed using a different method involving a `pem` file maybe? @sasharomanov

Comment: Did you try using some other user than root?

Comment: can you explain more about pem file or firewall settings , i'm using ssh command

Comment: `.pem` file is a security certificate used to gain access to servers(public key). If you use public-private key protection then you need this file to login to the server.

Comment: Your firewall manager must have port 22 open for ssh. Then remote access will work.

Comment: @sasharomanov Take a look at [ENABLE ROOT LOGIN OVER SSH](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/v2v_guide/preparation_before_the_p2v_migration-enable_root_login_over_ssh)

Comment: yes firewall is configured correctly as , i can run other commands directly from server even nodejs files , but pm2 can't run , i don't really know why

Comment: what does `whereis pm2` give?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194331/discussion-between-vishnudev-and-sasha-romanov).