# How to connect input/output to SSH session

Tags: linux, bash, file-descriptor

What is a good way to be able to directly send to STDIN and receive from STDOUT of a process?  I'm specifically interested in SSH, as I want to do the following:

```
[ssh into a remote server]
[run remote commands]
[run local commands]
[run remote commands]
 etc...
```

For example, let's say I have a local script "localScript" that will output the next command I want to run remotely, depending on the output of "remoteScript".  I could do something like:

```
output=$(ssh myServer "./remoteScript")
nextCommand=$(./localScript $output)
ssh myServer "$nextCommand"
```

But it would be nice to do this without closing/reopening the SSH connection at every step.

Comment: You mean run a command in a remote server, run a command, and use the output on your local machine?

Comment: That is the default behavior. Opening an ssh session to a remote server _automatically_ redirects STDIN, STDOUT, and STDERR to/from that process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect SSH input and output to FIFO-s and then use these for two-way communication.

For example `local.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

SSH_SERVER="myServer"

# Redirect SSH input and output to temporary named pipes (FIFOs)
SSH_IN=$(mktemp -u)
SSH_OUT=$(mktemp -u)
mkfifo "$SSH_IN" "$SSH_OUT"
ssh "$SSH_SERVER" "./remote.sh" < "$SSH_IN" > "$SSH_OUT" &

# Open the FIFO-s and clean up the files
exec 3>"$SSH_IN"
exec 4<"$SSH_OUT"
rm -f "$SSH_IN" "$SSH_OUT"

# Read and write
counter=0
echo "PING${counter}" >&3
cat <&4 | while read line; do
    echo "Remote responded: $line"
    sleep 1
    counter=$((counter+1))
    echo "PING${counter}" >&3
done
```

And simple `remote.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read line; do
    echo "$line PONG"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using works, but I don't think you can reuse the same connection everytime. You can, however, do this [using screen, tmux or nohup](https://www.tecmint.com/keep-remote-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection/), but that would greatly increase the complexity of your script because you will now have to emulate keypresses/shortcuts. I'm not even sure if you can if you do directly in bash. If you want to emulate keypresses, you will have to run the script in a new x-terminal and use [xdotool to emulate the keypresses](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267704/command-to-simulate-keyboard-input).

Another method is to delegate the whole script to the SSH server by just [running the script on the remote server itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-a-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine):

```sh
ssh root@MachineB 'bash -s' < local_script.sh
```