# bash script remote ssh ping on unit (cisco) results with half response

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, cisco

I'm trying to catch/pipe ping response from remote cisco router over ssh (see script). Everything works well but only at ping the pipe brokes at first "!" ping response from router destination:

```
routername#ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx source loopback xx
Type escape sequence to abort.Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, timeout is 2 seconds:
Packet sent with a source address of xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
!
```

And that's all... It seems to break after the first "!".

Where this works well and catch and give back whole ping result:

```
ssh "user@$1" 'ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx source loopback xx' > log
ssh user@$1 "ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx source loopback xx" | tee -a log
```

but only as single line command.
What can I do to catch the whole output until end?

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1"
var1=$(ssh user@$1 << "ENDSSH"
sh version | incl System image file
sh ip interface INTx  | incl MTU
show controllers VDx | incl Speed
sh cellular 0 radio | include RSS
sh cellular 0 netw | include Selected
ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx source loopback xx
ENDSSH)
echo "$var1" > log
```

Comment: maybe `var1="$(ssh ...)"` will help. Good luck.

Comment: You have to use [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it if I wanted to use var1 for more things later on;

```
var1=$(ssh user@$1 "ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx source loopback xx; SSHEND")

echo "$var1" > log
```

However it's only good if the text doesn't have control chars in it.

This would have the effect of hiding output from std out and is equivalent to;

```
ssh user@$1 "ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx source loopback xx; morecommands" > log
```

You may want the output in stdout and there are ways to that too.  I think it's;

```
ssh user@$1 "ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx source loopback xx" | tee -a log
```

When all else fails, put all your remote commands into a script and execute the script remotely.

a one liner;

```
tf=$(mktemp); echo "ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx source loopback xx">$tf; output=$(ssh user@$1 bash -s < $tf); echo $output; rm -f $tf
```

Comment: indeed... but i'm using some more commands inside ENDSSH, like show version and so on... while other are running well, the ping brokes after first ! ... i'm clueless why...

Comment: well you can separate commands in several ways, ';' will start a new command, '&&' will execute second if the first succeeds, and '||' if the first fails

The way you have your question stated, it is valid bash syntax to use ENDSSH as a label like you have, so perhaps expand your question to include your caveats.

Comment: hey calvin... thank you very much... only 
ssh user@$1 "ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx source loopback xx" | tee -a log
give me full response to log how that should be like
---
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 40/43/48 ms
----

Comment: how can i execute further commands in the same ssh? like: 
var1=$(ssh user@$1 << "ENDSSH"
sh version | incl System image file
sh ip interface INT1  | incl MTU
show controllers VDSL | incl Speed
sh cellular 0 radio | include RSSI
sh cellular 0 netwo | include Selected
ENDSSH
)
echo "$var1" > log

----
while those was previous allready ok and i get response from all of them except ping commands where the pipe to log broke after the first ping response sign from the router which is the exclamation mark "!"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-a-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine

Comment: the '!' is a control char and would need to be escaped, and I think that can be avoided by using a script.

Comment: hey Calvin... Thx for answering... How could I avoid that in my script?