# Unable to use variables in remote ssh command

Tags: bash, shell, heredoc

Wanted to create a directory in my remote server by executing the script from my local, expected directory is not getting created on the remote VM and no error message is given as well.

I tried to escape the variable using `\`, enclosed the variable in single as well as in double quotes, but of no luck..

What am I missing ?

```
#!/bin/bash

password="mypassword"
remote_ip="10.28.28.28"
dir_to_create="/home/rocket/DjangoDir"


sshpass -p ${password} ssh -q -tt user@${remote_ip} << 'EOT'
    mkdir -p \$dir_to_create
  exit
EOT
```

Also, tried `"\$dir_to_create"` , `\"$dir_to_create"` and `\"${dir_to_create}"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-a-local-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine

Comment: variables defined in the local script do not exist on the remote system. Why are you quoting them? Might they contain spaces or special characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables expansions are not executed in a here document with quoted delimiter. Use unquoted delimiter to allow expansions to happen.

Because the remote shell re-parses the expression, remember about properly quoting the variables. The remote may not execute shell on the remote side - explicitly execute your shell and read from `stdin`. Remember to quote variable expansions:

```
ssh "user@${remote_ip}" 'bash -s' <<EOT
mkdir -p $(printf "%q" "$dir_to_create")
EOT
```

Properly passing properly quoted variables is a hard job. Do not do it yourself - use `bash` features. For me the best stable and simple to use feature for to transfer locally defined work to remote context is to use a function:

```
func() {
    mkdir -p "$dir_to_create"
}
ssh "user@${remote_ip}" 'bash -s' <<EOT
$(declare -p dir_to_create) # transfer variables values
$(declare -f func)          # transfer function definition
func                        # call the function
EOT
```

Please research: quoting in shell - what to use, what does it mean, what it's effect is. Research `declare` - what does it do. Research here document - how does a quoted terminating word `<<'EOT'` differ from unquoted one `<<EOT`. Check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net .

Comment: Really appreciate the detailed explanation.

Comment: ShellCheck is really useful!