# VS Code "Open PHP With" Extension, Workspace: Remote Linux sys via Win11 SSH

Tags: php, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

Working Web Dev projects in VS Code, with the [Open PHP With...](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PrimaFuture.open-php-html-js-in-browser) extension activated, it's pretty easy to preview the php files/ server side changes, as that extension affords configuration of server root paths, and paths to browser executable.

However, this becomes "an issue" when attempting to "Open with" while connected to a Remote system.

The beauty of "Open PHP With" of course-- ideally-- the WorkSpace is configured w/ that extension such that whatever file you want to open, it's just a matter of right-click in the editor, Open-PHP.
Just looking around at StackOverflow, I came across a couple of posts where it's explained how to do some different tricks w/ [remote scripting - save output to local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-a-local-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine) system, etc. But I can't see that what I want should hardly be that complicated.

if you look at the error above, it's stating that /usr/bin/firefox won't open due to the DISPLAY:0 not being set. But, I have WSL running, so ... /usr/bin/firefox , if passed to the WSL commandline, would in fact open the "local" firefox. If that could happen, then the rest of the "Open PHP With" setup should function as desired. I've contacted the developer about it, but never received a reply.

There's a VS COde extension which claims to be able to config the DISPLAY var to work like that, but I could never figure out how to use it correctly, moreover what exactly i'm trying to configure with it. I've used Linux a fair amount, so I understand what DISPLAY:0 means, and why the app wont open/ why that error is thrown.

Does anyone have a recommended way of tweaking "Open With PHP" so the user can preview such a remote file without employing acrobatics?

Thank yoU!

The error returned is that the system can't launch the browser:

```
Unable to launch selected browser (Custom). Error: Command failed: /usr/bin/firefox "http://remote_apache/p54/index.php" Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified
```

It makes sens (i suppose...)
But, it also seems like "what's the point of the extension, if it cant do THAT!?". So, I question what am I doing wrong?: Seems it should be able to be configured (at least in a hack sort of way. E.g. [with WSL running] /wsl/usr/bin/firefox | [drive:]\prog files\moz\firefox.exe --new-tab "http://server/path/filename.php").