# bash - ssh and perform tasks based on OS

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to run OS (linux/AIX) specific commands across hosts and I am using for loop with if statement but when I execute it takes me into the host shell prompt, any thoughts?

```
for i in $(cat hosts); do
echo ---$i---; ssh -qt $i
  if [[ "$(uname)" = Linux ]];
  then
     df -h | grep tmp
  else
     df -g | grep tmp
  fi
done
```

The command is executed when I exit out of the command prompt and the pipe with grep seems to be ignored as well.

Comment: Did you consider using tools for that, like ansible, puppet, chef? `ssh -qt $i` - there is no command, what would you expect? If you intention to run the content of `if` inside ssh? Did you forgot `'` single quotes?

Comment: Also, I recommend using POSIX-compliant shell syntax.

Comment: To get some useful hints add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) to your script and then paste it at http://www.shellcheck.net/.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use SSH to run a local shell script on a remote machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-a-local-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine)  in your case that's two scripts, one to do the looping, the if for the far end.