Server hung up on ssh -T connection
I am trying connecting to an AWS instance with the following command:
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -t -i ec2-key.pem ${EC2_USER}@${EC2_HOST} <<EOF
docker stop users
echo ${DOCKER_PASSWORD} | docker login --username ${DOCKER_USERNAME} --password-stdin
docker pull ${DOCKER_REPO}/${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_VERSION}
docker run -d -p 27050:27050 --name "users" ${DOCKER_REPO}/${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_VERSION}
EOF

This is from a CI/CD pipeline, which also fails when running from the command line. It ends up here:
 * Ubuntu Pro delivers the most comprehensive open source security and
   compliance features.

   https://ubuntu.com/aws/pro

Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is not enabled.

25 updates can be applied immediately.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable

Enable ESM Apps to receive additional future security updates.
See https://ubuntu.com/esm or run: sudo pro status

and does not move further.
I can ssh into it without the -T flag, but I need it for the pipeline to run since I am running commands remotely on the server.
The issues seems to be with this line:
echo ${DOCKER_PASSWORD} | sudo docker login --username ${DOCKER_USERNAME} --password-stdin
since when running from my command line via shell script, it stops the docker container, but fails here with the error:
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
invalid reference format
docker: invalid reference format.

Have not been able to find useful answers here or elsewhere.

That just opens an SSH connection, which is then sitting there waiting for you to type something in the SSH terminal. It's going to sit there forever until someone types exit into the SSH terminal, or the terminal session times out due to inactivity. You need to pass it the commands to run as part of the ssh command, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-a-local-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine

I do run more commands.  See updated post.

If you run that same ssh thing locally, instead of in your CI/CD pipeline, does it work, or does it hang?

It hangs in the same way as it does from the pipeline.

Some additional errors though:
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
invalid reference format, docker: invalid reference format.

Why not just use docker login -u ${DOCKER_USERNAME} -p ${DOCKER_PASSWORD} ?

It is kinda best practice since the password does not make it to the shell history in this way.

The issue was the DOCKER_PASSWORD containing an & and a ' character. Once the password was corrected, the issue was resolved.
